# How to avoid the error "ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples"?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
"PathID","Area","Latitude","Longitude"
```

I tried first creating a geodataframe with

```
mygeom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(mydataframe.Longtitude,mydataframe.Latitude)]
mygeoframe = GeoDataFrame(mydataframe, geom=mygeom)
mylines = mygeoframe.groupby(['PathID','Area'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
```

My issue is some of my PathIDs only contain a single point so may not constitute a LineString..

```
ValueError: LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples
```

Is there a way I can bypass by filtering out the ones without 2 coordiante tuples in my lambda or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter those error-causing values, or you can handle the error use a try/catch block. I feel like the latter would be a better, simpler idea.

```
try:
    # line(s) that may throw an error
except ValueError:
    # either do something or continue
```

Again, you could also clean up the input and get rid of the trouble values instead. I just think this way is cleaner and potentially more efficient.